# Google play developer console not activated

Tags: google-play-console

I try to make developer account on play store and the fee is deducted but when try sign in it, it's takes me to register page while searching about this I found it take 48 hours to activate so try to wait but after 48 hours it still takes me to register page. I also try to mail but they are not replying what to do now ??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question. Ask Google Play support instead.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One Word ***Patient*** ... Google in their site mentioned that PROBABLY will be some delay. For my second account took me months.

```
Due to adjusted work schedules at this time, you may experience longer than usual review times for your app.

In order to help ensure we are providing users with accurate and timely information relating to COVID-19, we are currently prioritizing the review and publication of apps published, commissioned, or authorized by official government entities and public health organizations. Any apps referencing COVID-19, or related terms, must meet these requirements.
```

In Context if they take long time for reviewing apps, so is the account.

Reference : [citation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en)

Comment: it is taking about apps but my problem is related to developer console

Comment: i mentioned ``` In Context if they take long time for reviewing apps, so is the account.```'

Comment: For my second account it took months, no worry about that.

Comment: accounts are immediately created once you receive the receipt in your mail , your answer is correct for app publishing not for account creation , You can immediately access your developer account when paying the fee no wait is included and this is not mentioned anywhere in your reference